# iText 7 - how to ensure proper cleanup of resources on exceptions

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

For iText7, sample code (from https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-chapter-6 )

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Utils;

namespace Tutorial.Chapter06 {
    public class C06E04_88th_Oscar_Combine {
        public const String SRC1 = "../../../resources/pdf/88th_reminder_list.pdf";

        public const String SRC2 = "../../../resources/pdf/88th_noms_announcement.pdf";

        public const String DEST = "../../../results/chapter06/88th_oscar_combined_documents.pdf";

        public static void Main(String[] args) {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
            file.Directory.Create();
            new C06E04_88th_Oscar_Combine().CreatePdf(DEST);
        }

        public virtual void CreatePdf(String dest) {
            //Initialize PDF document with output intent
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
            //Add pages from the first document
            PdfDocument firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
            merger.Merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, firstSourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages());
            //Add pages from the second pdf document
            PdfDocument secondSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC2));
            merger.Merge(secondSourcePdf, 1, secondSourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages());
            firstSourcePdf.Close();
            secondSourcePdf.Close();
            pdf.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm not sure about, is whether resources like open files will be cleaned up properly, if an exception occurs inside a method like CreatePdf. Is there a way to rewrite CreatePdf, perhaps using "using" blocks etc., that could ensure more robust clean up if/when things go wrong ? Or is the code, as written, robust enough for real life use ?

Comment: You mean deleted in case of exception?

Comment: @Magnus - ideally, if there is an exception in CreatePdf, then the dest file should not be created. What would you guys who work with iText do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `using` on objects that implements `IDisposable` to ensure they  are disposed when you leave the function (and in case of exception). You dont need to call `Close` on them. And add a catch to delete the file.

```
public virtual void CreatePdf(String dest) 
{
  try
  {
      using var writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
      ...
  } 
  catch (Exception)
  {
    File.Delete(dest);
    throw;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `using` keywrod when you initiazlize object of class that implements `IDisposable`:

```
public virtual void CreatePdf(String dest) {
    using PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    
    //Initialize PDF document with output intent
    using PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
    
    using PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC1);
    
    //Add pages from the first document
    using PdfDocument firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(reader);
    merger.Merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, firstSourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages());
    
    using PdfReader otherReader = new PdfReader(SRC2);
    //Add pages from the second pdf document
    using PdfDocument secondSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(otherReader);
    
    merger.Merge(secondSourcePdf, 1, secondSourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages());
}
```

Secondly I recommend using [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations#implicitly-typed-local-variables) keyword for cleaner code.